# Possible to add user submitted marker to a leaflet map via submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am running into a problem trying to save a leaflet marker on my map which is placed by the user. Currently, they click and it adds the marker where they clicked. Upon clicking again it will zoom in, and open a popup that has two fields to enter information with a submit button at the end. They can also drag or click to move the marker without creating more of them.

Ideally this will be linked to a database to store the inputs from the user. The guy who will be doing that is using SQlite3 and Ruby/Rails which I know little about. Right now when I click submit after filling in the data with GET in the search bar, the page refreshes and the marker disappears. Is it possible to have the marker appear on the map as well? I've tried searching around and nothing appears for adding the marker this way

Here is the code I have so far, I'm not an expert by any means. Which probably explains why I can't figure this out.

```
// User Marker

var currentMarker;

map.on("click", function (event) {
   if (currentMarker) {
    currentMarker._icon.style.transition = "transform 0.3s ease-out";
    currentMarker._shadow.style.transition = "transform 0.3s ease-out";        
    currentMarker.setLatLng(event.latlng);

    setTimeout(function () {
        currentMarker._icon.style.transition = null;
        currentMarker._shadow.style.transition = null;
    }, 300);
    return;
}

currentMarker = L.marker(event.latlng, {
    draggable: true,
    icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
    icon: 'exclamation-circle',
    markerColor: 'orange',
    iconColor: '#F8FAEE',           
})    


}).addTo(map).on("click", function (e) {
    map.setView(e.latlng, 17);
    alert("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
    event.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
}).bindPopup('<form role="form" id="form" onsubmit="addMarker()">'+

      '<div class="form-group">'+
          '<label class="control-label col-sm-10"><strong>Type of Complaint </strong></label>'+ "<br>" +
          '<select class="form-control" id="toc" name="toc">'+
            '<option value="Pothole">Pothole</option>'+
            '<option value="Construction">Construction</option>'+
            '<option value="Road Closed">Road Closed</option>'+
            '<option value="Other">Other...</option>'+
          '</select>'+ 
      '</div>'+

      '<div class="form-group2">'+
          '<label class="control-label col-sm-10"><strong>Description of Complaint </strong></label>'+ "<br>" +
          '<input type="text" placeholder="Extra Information" id="doc" name="extra" class="form-control"/>'+ 
      '</div>'+

        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<div style="text-align:center;" class="col-xs-11"><button style="text-align:center;" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary trigger-submit">Submit</button></div>'+
      '</div>'+ "<br>" +

             '</form>');
});

document.getElementById("done").addEventListener("click", function () {
  currentMarker = null;

});
```

If any more information is needed let me know, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page refreshed because your form triggers a submit event. When the submit is triggered the page will post a GET request to the same page itself as a target is not defined. To disable the refresh you will have to return a false value to the onsubmit property of the form.

When you bind the popup, add a return statement with the method.

```
'<form role="form" id="form" onsubmit="return addMarker();">'+
```

Secondly define the addMarker method. In this method you could add a AJAX request to a service to send the data & push it to your database asynchronously.

```
var addMarker = function(){
   //Get the data from the form & send it to the service.
   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "someservice.php",
     data: { toc: "your type", description: " your description" }
   })
   .done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });

   return false; //Don't submit anything
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, if I follow what you instructed me to do. The marker that they filled out will appear on the map until the data is deleted from the database? I'm having problems trying to make the marker appear continuously. I was able to get constant markers working, ones that I created. Though trying to make a user marker appear during a refresh or coming back to the site is where I run into problems. Thank you though for the insight.

Comment: To keep previously created markers after a page refresh you would have to pull them from the database through some service & recreate them.